# Incrementing value if it exists in JOIN table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, increment

**Models:**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :longitude, :latitude, :radius, :name
  has_many :statistics
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :stat_type_id, :updated, :count, :location_id
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :stat_type
end

class StatType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :statistics
end
```

I can update a record like this:

```
statistic = @@location.statistics.build(:count => 1, :updated => updated, :stat_type_id => @@stat_type.id)
statistic.save
```

Currently a new record is always created.  However, I want to change this so `count` gets incremented rather than given the value `1`.

I know `increment` exists: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment but I'm not sure how to use it in my case (with this JOIN).  How can I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using `@@location.statistics.build(:count => @@location.statistics.count` ?

Comment: this just creates a new record?  Rather than updates?.. How can I change this behaviour?  Thanks :)

Comment: With the solution I proposed you can keep a trace of the stats by date: on the december 5th: count was 5, december 10th: count was 7, etc etc. If you don't need the history of the stats, you may need to change the has_many :statistics to a has_one :statistic. I need more informations to help you about htis

Comment: Would you like me to post an answer to show you my point?

Comment: I basically need what you suggested but the count will be incremented multiple times.. so "on the december 5th: count was 5, december 10th: count was 7" but each of these days will have their counts incremented possibly many times